# Command that outputs at the end of the document the pages and line numbers where it was used

Tags: page-numbering, expansion, line-numbering

I need to a command that outputs at the end of the document the pages and line numbers where it was used.
I've tried different variants of the following code but my knowledge of latex is limited. I'm using `lineno` for line number and `endnotes` for having the notes at the end of the document. 
I think some knowledge about latex expansion could help me but didn't get it so far.

In the example below, I get all the end notes with the page and line number of the last use of the `revised` command.

Can you help me to correctly get the page and line numbers of the uses of the command? Thank you!

```
\usepackage{endnotes}
\let\footnote=\endnote

\usepackage[pagewise,switch]{lineno}
\linenumbers

\newcounter{modification}

\newcommand{\revised}[2]{%
    \stepcounter{modification}
    \linelabel{ln:line\arabic{modification}}
    #1
    \footnote{#2. Page \pageref{ln:line\arabic{modification}}, Line \ref{ln:line\arabic{modification}}, Counter \arabic{modification}}
}% revision with footnote

\begin{document}

\revised{New text 1.}{Reason of change 1.}
\revised{New text 2.}{Reason of change 2.}
\revised{New text 3.}{Reason of change 3.}

\theendnotes

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to expand `\arabic{modification}` on the spot, or it would be written literally in the auxiliary file for the endnotes.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{endnotes}

\usepackage[pagewise,switch]{lineno}
\linenumbers

\newcounter{modification}

\newcommand{\revised}[2]{%
  \stepcounter{modification}%
  \begingroup\edef\x{\endgroup
    \noexpand\linelabel{ln:line\arabic{modification}}%
  }\x
  #1%
  \begingroup\edef\x{\endgroup
    \noexpand\endnote{\unexpanded{#2}. Page \noexpand\pageref{ln:line\arabic{modification}}, 
      Line \noexpand\ref{ln:line\arabic{modification}}, Counter \arabic{modification}}%
  }\x
}% revision with footnote

\begin{document}

\revised{New text 1.}{Reason of change 1.}

\revised{New text 2.}{Reason of change 2.}

\revised{New text 3.}{Reason of change 3.}

\nolinenumbers

\theendnotes

\end{document}
```

I suggest not to redefine `\footnote`, but to use `\endnote`.

[image]

The code is less convoluted using `xparse` that allows to better control expansion. The code from `\newcounter{modification}` up to `\begin{document}` can be changed into

```
\usepackage{xparse}

\newcounter{modification}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\revised}{mm}
 {
  \stepcounter{modification}
  \jb_revised:fnn { \arabic{modification} } { #1 } { #2 }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \jb_revised:nnn
 {
  \linelabel{ln:line#1}
  #2
  \endnote{#3.~Page~\pageref{ln:line#1},~Line~\ref{ln:line#1},~Counter~#1}
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \jb_revised:nnn { f }
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

with the same result.

Comment: Impressive. I'll need time to digest it :) Works flawlessly. Thank you for the suggestions.

Comment: @JB Both versions fully expand `\arabic{modification}` before emitting `\linelabel` and `\endnote`. The full expansion is actually only needed for `\endnote`, otherwise LaTeX would write `\arabic{modification}` in the auxiliary `.ent` file, instead of the current value.